# Xamarin App Exception: "Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I tried building a simple Xamarin Forms application that groups a list of contacts. in this case I only had two contacts to keep it easy. When launching the app on the iOS-Simulator or on my iPhone 6s (iOS 12) an error appears that says:

> "{Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSPlaceholderString
>   initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString Native stack trace:    0
>   CoreFoundation  0x00000001068e56fb __exceptionPrepr…}"

c#

```
namespace Lists{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView.ItemsSource = new List<ContactGroup> {
                new ContactGroup("P", "P")
                {
                    new Contact { Name = "Peter Parker", Status = "Nice to meet you!" }
                },
                new ContactGroup("J", "J")
                {
                    new Contact { Name = "John Smith", Status = "Hey, let's talk!" }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactGroup : List<Contact>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortTitle { get; set; }

        public ContactGroup(string title, string shortTitle)
        {
            Title = title;
            ShortTitle = shortTitle; 
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    Padding="0, 20, 0, 0"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lists" x:Class="Lists.MainPage">

    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
              GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding shortTitle}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
  GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding shortTitle}">
```

You should set binding to **ShortTitle**  instead of `shortTitle`.

Here is a demo with the code and you can check it: [grouped-listView](https://github.com/XfHua/Grouped-ListView-xamarin.forms)

Comment: @Dariush It should work, I tested it on my side and I will share you the project. You could try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @Dariush  Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't find the problem with my solution but yours works perfectly.